# Speeding up AWS EC2 using MEAN

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, varnish, mean-stack

I recently opened a AWS server with a t1.micro EC2 instance. I have MEAN, forever, nginx, and varnish running but it's still extremely slow to access the website.

Over the EC2 server my mean app is super slow. When I'm in localhost:3000, it's really fast. Any ideas?

Comment: Micro instances are usually run alongside with noisy neighbours on the same hardware, that makes it slow. Varnish can be replaced with Nginx caching mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get better/faster network for t1.micro w/ default settings, it has slow network speed. also, pick the nearest zone for you.

you can comment this out, Gruntfile.js to disable livereload

```js
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
    //livereload: 35729 <---- this
```

Comment: I found the issue, it was a livereload problem with grunt. I'm using a yeoman's generated page. By any chance, would you happen to know if livereload is relevant? Can I just disable it?

Comment: I've edited my first post to  disable the livereload, please see

Comment: Thanks again, but i found the main reason why it's lagging so badly on my EC2 instance. I was running my mean app in development mode, I had to set it to production mode using this website, http://www.hacksparrow.com/running-express-js-in-production-mode.html